# MongoDB: Get whole document with aggregate method

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, nosql

I'm trying to reach something like this:
I have collections of activities that belong to some user.
I want to get the activity names distincted ordered by 'added_time', so I used 'group by' on the activity name and get the max value of 'added_time'.
Also, I want to sort them by 'added_time', and then to get the whole document.
The only thing that I reached so far, is to get only the name that I grouped by, and the 'added_time' property.
This is the query:

```
db.getCollection('user_activities').aggregate
(
  {$match: {'type': 'food', 'user_id': '123'}},
  {$group:{'_id':'$name', 'added_time':{$max:'$added_time'}}}, 
  {$sort:{'added_time':-1}},
  {$project: {_id: 0,name: "$_id",count: 1,sum: 1, 'added_time': 1}}
)
```

Can someone help me with reaching the whole document?
Thank's!

Comment: You can try `db.getCollection('user_activities').aggregate(
  {$sort:{'name':1, 'added_time':-1}},
 {$group:{'_id':'$name', 'doc':{$first:'$$ROOT'}}}
)`

Comment: But how do I make the doc to be the main element instead of being nested?

Comment: Add `{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$doc" } }` as the last stage to promote doc to top level in 3.4 version

Comment: @Veeram Thank's man! It works exactly like I want it to be! :)